# Eclipse github How to change my Project message when i have pushed

Tags: eclipse, github

I first commit blog, the messages is ok.

When I push next time, the message is no change.

I check my history, these were be pushed

What is master & HEAD?

How to change my Project message when I have pushed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you made another commit before the next push? It needs to happen every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To modify a commit message right-click the commit and choose *Modify > Reword***. Technically, changing the commit message means to replace the commit and all its subsequent commits with a new commit due the message and the references to the parent(s) are part of the commit (you can see this by the fact that the Id of the commit has changed).

If you have already pushed the replaced commenit, the rewritten Git history requires a ***force-push***: **right-click** the `HEAD` commit and choose ***Push Commit...***. In the *Push Branch master* dialog **check the option *Force overwrite branch in remote if it exist and has diverged***. But beware, rewriting the remote Git history is problematic when you collaborate with others via your GitHub repository. Therefor [GitHub allows to disable force pushing](https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks).

> What is master & HEAD?

The commit where you are (in your local repository) is marked with `HEAD`. The latest/head commit of a branch is marked with the branch name: `master` is the name of the main/default branch (like `trunk` in SVN/Subversion).